# Confused about a program about finding factors

Tags: python-3.6

I was searching the web about finding factors and saw the one below
I was confused about it and wanted some help
I don't know what it means

This is for a project that we are making which is to make a game to find factors in which users have to input a number and the program will show the factors
I've tried putting

```
   if ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
```

but it doesn't work, I wanted the program to say "Sorry, I didn't understand that." if the user typed a letter or special character

how do I loop it too if the user typed a letter or special character

```
   def print_factors(x):
      print("The factors of",x,"are:")
      for i in range(1, x + 1):
      if x % i == 0:
         print(i)

    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    print_factors(num)
```

the program works but I can't seem to add loops and the value error thing on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try catch block, and catch the valueError exception. Like below

```
def print_factors(x):
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i)


try:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print_factors(num)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! ummm can i ask another favor what does the program mean i'm very confused to what it means especially the top half part and the try thingy

Comment: and also why does the program not work without try?

Comment: When you try to convert non numeric string to int, suppose the input was 'abc' or any other non numeric string, it will throw an ValueError. 
 int(input('Enter a number)) => input is 'ab' => int('ab')  => This will throw ValueError.
the statements that throw the Error or exceptions are to be kept inside try block. immediately after the try block catch block should be placed. The catch block will catch the exception throw from the try block and executes the statements written in catch block. Note: Once the error is thrown, the statements next to line which threw error are not executed further

Comment: how about the top part?

Comment: Enter a number: a

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Desktop/tst.py", line 9, in <module>
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> 




I tried to use it and it gives me this error if i put an alphabet or a special character